# Input type file for android 2.2

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to am trying to make a input type file browse option in html for android 2.2.
here is my code...Please help me to make this option.

```
<android:input name="File Upload" type="file" id="File Upload"  />
 <input name="File Upload" type="file" id="File Upload"  />
```

I am new to android development. Your help appreciated

Comment: Can't understand the mix between HTML and Android Layouts. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: I guess, Sanket wants to send files (for example, pics) to server from his app.

Comment: We shouldn't have to guess what the question is.  It needs to be obvious - what he wants, what he's tried.  "Help me make this option". What option? "input type file browse option in html". Pardon me?

Comment: He  want to upload file from his app. to server

Answer (score 0):

I think you are way new to android than i thought when u said "I am new to android development.". The code you are trying to use is not an android xml but a html code with android tags added at beginning and last. I think  you should use the visual xml designer on android or third party apps like droiddraw.org for that. Also check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html for reference. And don't worry, everyone is new to everything at first. Good luck :)